# jquery applies function on all classes error

Tags: jquery

I wrote this and it works how it supposed to but I'm not sure how to get this effect only on the div with class .pro-slika I'm hovering on and not on all classes named .pro-slika

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pro-slika').hover(function() {
        $('.crna-tran').fadeToggle();
        $('.websitename').slideToggle();
        $('.lupo').fadeToggle(); 
    });
});
```

I know I'm supposed to use 'this' but not sure how.

Comment: Are `crna-tran`, `websitename`, and `lupo` classes *inside* the `pro-slika` element? Can you show some HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming your `.crna-tran` and other classes are found inside the `.pro-slika` class, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pro-slika').hover(function() {      
        var $hoveredEl = $(this);
        $hoveredEl.find('.crna-tran').fadeToggle();
        $hoveredEl.find('.websitename').slideToggle();
        $hoveredEl.find('.lupo').fadeToggle(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Store and reuse $(this) for better performance.  Also if the order is not critical, you could combine the first and last one with .find('.crna-tran, .lupo')

Comment: @Taplar there is very little performance improvement when just wrapping an element as opposed to selecting elements from the DOM. Anyway, it's a good best practice, so why not? :D

Comment: Always a plus to reinforce better practices in the case that you need them, :)